# Сортировка в python

Tags: python, сортировка

Доброго времени суток
Есть такой массив:

```
   [[-0.08389921  0.19594724 -0.94168127 -0.26038826]
    [-0.08345754  0.19559757 -0.94191563 -0.25994498]
    [ 0.19331953 -0.11434945 -0.93220872 -0.28379342]
    ..., 
    [ 0.00371751  0.20588334 -0.9404704  -0.27039546]
    [ 0.23030412 -0.32481459 -0.87476689 -0.276113  ]
    [ 0.0456914   0.2426361  -0.93415111 -0.25768542]]
```

В каждой строке первые три элемента это x,y,z координаты точки в пространстве. Пытаюсь отсортировать массив по увеличению расстояний в пространстве между точками

```
res = sorted(result1,key=cmp_to_key(sort_dist))
```

функция сортировки

```
def sort_dist(A, B):
        return math.sqrt((A[0] - B[0])**2 + (A[1] - B[1])**2 + (A[2] - B[2])**2)
```

В чем проблема? Он вообще не сортирует. А если я сделаю функцию к примеру такой:

```
def sort_dist(A, B):
    return (A[0] - B[0])
```

то все ок.

Comment: это Numpy матрица?

Comment: да, но не суть, я потом обратно в numpy перегоняю
суть в том, что не сортирует.
если что, то и проверял на обычном списке (чтобы вопросы не возникали)

Comment: 4-й столбец значения не имеет?

Comment: квадратный корень всегда больше нуля, сортировка не может понять какой больше какой меньше.

Comment: да, 4 столбец не важен

Comment: Посчитайте сразу расстояния для каждого объекта и сортируйте их. Тогда можно обойтись обычным вычитанием

Comment: таки считать для каждой точки с каждой вручную затратно

Comment: понял вроде, попробую реализовать
отпишусь о результатах

Comment: я не совсем понимаю что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: @MaxU *таки считать для каждой точки с каждой* теперь и я не понимаю :)))

Comment: Функции в `scipy.spatial.distance` позволяют посчитать все расстояния за один вызов - главное понимать какие расстояния мы хотим посчитать...

Comment: да, я понял вас:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, cdist, squareform, euclidean


In [25]: a = np.random.randint(10, size=(5,4))

In [26]: a
Out[26]:
array([[3, 7, 1, 0],
       [0, 4, 8, 3],
       [1, 2, 2, 9],
       [5, 5, 8, 9],
       [8, 5, 2, 4]])
```

Решение:

```
In [28]: a[np.argsort(pdist(a[:, :3])[:len(a)-1])]
Out[28]:
array([[0, 4, 8, 3],
       [5, 5, 8, 9],
       [1, 2, 2, 9],
       [3, 7, 1, 0]])
```

Пояснения:

```
In [29]: pdist(a[:, :3])[:len(a)-1]
Out[29]: array([ 8.18535277,  5.47722558,  7.54983444,  5.47722558])

In [30]: np.argsort(pdist(a[:, :3])[:len(a)-1])
Out[30]: array([1, 3, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

для наглядности можно создать Pandas DataFrame с расстояниями между всеми попарными комбинациями точек (назовем их по порядку от `0` до `4`):

```
import pandas as pd

In [31]: r = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(a[:, :3])), columns=range(len(a)), index=range(len(a)))

In [32]: r
Out[32]:
          0          1         2         3          4
0  0.000000   8.185353  5.477226  7.549834   5.477226
1  8.185353   0.000000  6.403124  5.099020  10.049876
2  5.477226   6.403124  0.000000  7.810250   7.615773
3  7.549834   5.099020  7.810250  0.000000   6.708204
4  5.477226  10.049876  7.615773  6.708204   0.000000
```

Comment: Получается расстояния только посчитались между соседними точками (в данном случае строках массива), так?

Comment: `pdist()` считает все расстояния, просто я выбрал только первую строку квадратной матрицы (т.е. расстояние от точки `0` до всех остальных), т.к. точно не знаю что вы хотите получить на выходе... ;)

Comment: Вот DataFrame это круто. Я только не понял, куда он дел последнюю строку?

Comment: @СергейСамойлов, вроде бы все строки и столбцы на месте - матрица (5 х 5)

Comment: после сортировки получили 4x5. То есть 4x4. Был же 5x4

Comment: Тупанул. стоит len(a)-1. Теперь все встало на свои места. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @СергейСамойлов, да, там отсутствует расстояние между точкой `0` и точкой `0` (т.е. сам с собой)... Это "решение" просто пример... Вот если сможете объяснить что вам надо получить на выходе, тогда можно будет поработать над настоящим решением... ;-)

Comment: Так я получил что мне нужно! Мне просто нужно было точки отсортировать по их расстоянию. То есть сначала соседи с минимальным расстоянием и т.д. Спасибо! Премного благодарен!